# If $\lim_{h\to 0}[f(x+h)-f(x+h)]=0$ for all $x$ then $f$ is not necessarily continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}\to  \mathbb{R}$ be a function. If, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, it holds that $$\lim_{h \to 0} [f(x+h) - f(x+h)] = 0$$
>
> then this would imply that $f$ is continuous ?

Solution:

> No.

But I don't know how to justify this result.

Comment: $f(x+h)-f(x+h)=0$ for any function.

Comment: I think you meant limit of $f(x+h) - f(x-h) $ otherwise the question makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer with $x+h$ in second term changed to $x-h$. Take $f(x)=x$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's actually kind of silly. $f(x+h) - f(x+h) =0$, with no limit required.